# How do I use a path stored in table with OPENROWSET?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, openrowset

I have just recently began using `OPENROWSET` to insert images into a table. Previously, I would specify the path to each image (1 image = 1 `INSERT` statement), and use PHP to generate the image's binary string:

```sql
INSERT INTO nopCommerce..Picture (PictureBinary, MimeType, SeoFilename, AltAttribute, TitleAttribute, IsNew)
VALUES (
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '" . $this->image['path'] . "', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Binary
    ),
    '" . $this->image['mime_type'] . "',
    '" . $this->image['seo_filename'] . "',
    '" . $this->image['alt'] . "',
    '',
    0
)
```

However, I am trying to insert all images with a single query. So, I have began storing the path to each image into a table, and now I need to insert each one as I did before (just using the table's path field instead of a PHP string). But, when I attempt the following:

```
INSERT INTO nopCommerce..Picture (PictureBinary, MimeType, SeoFilename, AltAttribute, TitleAttribute, IsNew)
SELECT
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ImagePath, SINGLE_BLOB) AS Binary
    ),
    MimeType,
    Name,
    Alt,
    '',
    0
FROM nopRMS..Product_Image_Mappings
```

I receive the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near 'ImagePath'.

So, I tried adding quotes around the column's name (to no avail):

```
INSERT INTO nopCommerce..Picture (PictureBinary, MimeType, SeoFilename, AltAttribute, TitleAttribute, IsNew)
SELECT
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'ImagePath', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Binary
    ),
    MimeType,
    Name,
    Alt,
    '',
    0
FROM nopRMS..Product_Image_Mappings
```

> Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot bulk load. The file "ImagePath" does not exist.

There has to be a way to accomplish this, I just cannot find the proper syntax online anywhere. Does anyone know how to tell SQL Server to get the path (string) from `dbo.Product_Image_Mappings.ImagePath`?

**UPDATE**
I forgot to give you an example of a value that `dbo.Product_Image_Mappings.ImagePath` would return. It's paths like `\\DEREK\WebImages\1\ca-82300.jpg`...

**UPDATE**
It appears that Eirikur Eiriksson has provided a solution in [this thread](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1570821-3077-1.aspx), but this looks like an overly-complicated method of achieving the same end...

**UPDATE (Attempt Using Eirikur Eiriksson's Method)**

```
DECLARE @SQL_STR NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @SQL_STR = STUFF(
    (
        SELECT 
            N'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT '
            + N'(SELECT X.BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '
            + NCHAR(39) + im.ImagePath + NCHAR(39)
            + N', SINGLE_BLOB) AS X) AS PictureBinary,'
            + NCHAR(39) + im.MimeType + NCHAR(39)
            + N' AS MimeType,'
            + NCHAR(39) + im.Name + NCHAR(39)
            + N' AS SeoFilename,'
            + NCHAR(39) + REPLACE(im.Alt, '''', '''''') + NCHAR(39)
            + N' AS AltAttribute,'
            + N'NULL AS TitleAttribute,'
            + N'0 AS IsNew'
        FROM nopRMS..Product_Image_Mappings im
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,12,N''
)

INSERT INTO nopCommerce..Picture (PictureBinary, MimeType, SeoFilename, AltAttribute, TitleAttribute, IsNew)
EXEC (@SQL_STR);
```

This kinda worked, but it only inserted 42 rows (out of 7200+)... I need this to be 100% accurate :( I admit though, I may need to change something about this query, but I don't know anything about it (aside from the basic INSERT, SELECT, etc.)

Comment: I should also mention that I am using this insert statement inside of a merge statement. I believe this may limit my options as well (because it looks like Dynamic SQL is the only option, and I don't believe that I can execute Dynamic SQL inside of `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET`.

Comment: FYI: I updated the formatting a little in the Question, but also the name of the person who posted that code on the SQL Server Central forum. The term "SSCertifiable" is not a name but a label associated with how many points and/or logins to the site one has.

Comment: You have PHP code in your first code sample. Are you building SQL inside a PHP page and running it? It's important to know. Your second code attempt (using 'ImagePath') might be achievable using a cursor - a cursor builds the full dynamic string for every record and executes it, but it'd be slow.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - Yes, I have been constructing the query in PHP then executing it with the SQLSRV drivers. TBH, speed is not necessarily a concern here. This app is a CLI app that runs every X minutes to synchronize our point of sale and our web app. So, as long as it takes less than 5-10 minutes to execute, it'd work just fine. I've heard of cursors, but I do not know how to use them with this driver... Can you elaborate on what is possible with cursors and my question please? Thanks!

Comment: **Regarding the Erik-Update**: Not quite sure exactly what the point of the extra complication of FOR XML is about. I'd just build a sql-string and EXEC it. But my first impression about the "42 rows (out of 7200+)..." is that only 42 of the rows in nopRMS..Product_Image_Mappings had all non-null values for the columns you used. One null in the string concatenation will wipe out that entire statement in the overall query you're building since CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is normally on. COALESCE() is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe don't use `OPENROWSET`? What you are wanting can be handled in a much simpler and cleaner manner using SQLCLR. You can create a Scalar UDF to just read the contents of a file and return that as a `VARBINARY(MAX)`. Then it will fit in nicely to your existing query. For example:

```sql
INSERT INTO nopCommerce.dbo.Picture (PictureBinary, MimeType, SeoFilename, 
                      AltAttribute, TitleAttribute, IsNew)
SELECT
    dbo.GetBinaryFile([ImagePath]) AS [PictureBinary],
    MimeType,
    Name,
    Alt,
    '',
    0
FROM nopRMS.dbo.Product_Image_Mappings;
```

And how much code does it take for `dbo.GetBinaryFile()`? Here it is:

```cs
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

[return:SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)]
[SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = false, IsPrecise = true)]
public static SqlBytes GetBinaryFile([SqlFacet(MaxSize = 1000)] SqlString FilePath)
{
    if (FilePath.Value.Trim().Equals(String.Empty))
    {
        return SqlBytes.Null;
    }

    return new SqlBytes(File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath.Value));
}
```

And the T-SQL wrapper object is the following (please note the `WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT` line as it skips execution if `NULL` is passed in, hence no need to check for `FilePath.IsNull` in the C# code :-)

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetBinaryFile](@FilePath NVARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARBINARY(MAX)
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
 EXTERNAL NAME [CSVParser].[CSVUtils].[GetBinaryFile];
```

The Assembly will need to be marked as `WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS`. Many people go the easy route of setting the database property of `TRUSTWORTHY` to `ON` in order to accomplish this, but that is a security risk and isn't even necessary. Just do the following and you can set the Assembly to `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` while keeping `TRUSTWORTHY` set to `OFF`:

1. Sign the Assembly.
2. Create an Asymmetric Key in `master` from that DLL.
3. Create a Login (also in `master`) from that Asymmetric Key.
4. Grant the new Login the `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` permission.

You can find detailed instructions on how to do this in Visual Studio / SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) in the following article that I wrote: [Stairway to SQLCLR Level 7: Development and Security](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQLCLR/138155/) (that site does require free registration in order to view the content).

Also, for anyone that does not want to bother with creating / deploying the Assembly, a similar function is available (though not for free) in the Full version of the [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com) library (which I created, and while many functions are free, the **File_*** file system functions are only in the Full version).

Comment: This might work :) I will build this assembly and try it out. Thank you for this!